# JavaScript formdata multiple upload

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to upload multiple files to a server using an ajax call.

Here is the code, every-time I am using it I am getting an upload error. The post  is not working in the html side.

Below is the code I have used in html and php.

**HTML**

```
  <input name="fileToUploadName"  id="fileinput0" type='file' />   
  <input name="fileToUploadName"  id="fileinput1" type='file' />   
  <input name="fileToUploadName"  id="fileinput2" type='file' />
```

**JS**

```
function upload(){
    var formdata = new FormData();
    var image0 = $('#fileinput0')[0].files[0];
    if(image0)
       formdata.append('fileToUpload[]',image0);

    var image1 = $('#fileinput1')[0].files[0];
    if(image1)
       formdata.append('fileToUpload[]',image1);


    var image2 = $('#fileinput2')[0].files[0];
    if(image2)
       formdata.append('fileToUpload[]',image2);


  $.ajax({
        url: 'server.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        async: true,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
                 alert(data);

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          var p =0;
           alert("Error uploading data");
         },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

}
```

**server.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
    foreach ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] as $key => $error)
    {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$key];
            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($name);

            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploadfile))
            {
                echo "Success: File ".$name." uploaded.<br/>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error: File ".$name." cannot be uploaded.<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But every time I am getting an upload error.

Comment: What error are you getting on console?

Comment: There's a simple error - `url: 'serever.php';`

Comment: Actually that's typing mistake, I have edited it.

Comment: Why are using same `name` for input field?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here, in your JavaScript file:

```
url: 'serever.php';
```

This should be

```
url: 'server.php';
```

This is, however, a simple typographical error.